# OpenCV number of SIFT matches ever as the first keypoint numbers

Tags: c++, opencv, matching, sift, feature-extraction

Using this code, when i print the number of matches i get the same number as the number of the keypoints found in the first image... 
For example one output could be

number of keypoints1: 682

number of keypoints2: 159

number of matches (FLANN): 682

number of matches (Brute Force): 682

how can be the matches more then the number of keypoints in the second image? I expect that the number of matches is less or equal to the minimum between the number of keypoints of the two images.

```
cv::SiftFeatureDetector  detector;
    detector = SiftFeatureDetector(
                                    0, // nFeatures
                                    4, // nOctaveLayers
                                    0.04, // contrastThreshold
                                    10, //edgeThreshold
                                    1.6 //sigma
                                    );


    std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1, keypoints2;

    int dxP = gray1.rows / 10;

    cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(gray1.size(), CV_8U); // all 0
    mask(Rect(dxP, dxP, gray1.cols - 2*dxP, gray1.rows - 2*dxP)) = 1;

    detector.detect(gray1, keypoints1, mask);
    cout << "number of keypoints1: " << keypoints1.size() << endl;

    detector.detect(gray2, keypoints2, mask);
    cout << "number of keypoints2: " << keypoints2.size() << endl;

    SiftDescriptorExtractor extractor;
    Mat descriptors1, descriptors2;
    extractor.compute(gray1, keypoints1, descriptors1);
    extractor.compute(gray2, keypoints2, descriptors2);

    //Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN matcher
    FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
    std::vector< DMatch > matches;
    matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);
    cout << "number of matches (FLANN): " << matches.size() << endl;

    // Matching descriptor vectors using Brute Force matcher
    BFMatcher BFmatcher(NORM_L2);
    vector<DMatch> BFmatches;
    BFmatcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, BFmatches);

    cout << "number of matches (Brute Force): " << BFmatches.size() << endl;
```

Comment: not 100% sure but I guess that a full matching is computed from first set to second set. This means, that for each descriptor of the first set, the closest descriptor of the second set is searched. So if |s1| > |s2| there will be several descriptors of s1 be matched to the same descriptor of s2. Just use the `CROSS-CHECK` parameter of http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html#bfmatcher-bfmatcher

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the orders of the parameters, to achieve your need invert the order:

```
matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);
```

to

```
matcher.match(descriptors2, descriptors1, matches);
```

Be careful on the order used, even the OpenCV docs confuses the order of the `matcher.match` call and laters inverts the `matches[i].trainIdx` and `matches[i].queryIdx`

the first parameter of the `::match` refers to the queryDescriptors (i.e. `queryIdx`)